# How do I include files with no extension for my Xtext DSL?

Tags: eclipse, content-type, dsl, xtext

By default Xtext allows to specify a single extension for DSL files when creating a new project. However, it is possible to add more extensions for a single DSL as described in [Xtext FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xtext/FAQ#How_do_I_enable_multiple_file_extensions_for_a_single_DSL.3F). But I couldn't get it working with files with no extension at all.

A typical example is a makefile for [Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names) build system. One can use `Makefile`, `GNUmakefile` and `*.mk` names, and Eclipse will open the same editor for such files.

I want to get Xtext to recognize both `*.mydsl` files and a file named `Mydsl`.

I tried to add

```
filenames="Mydsl"
```

attribute to `editor` node of `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point in `plugin.xml` of my UI project. This enables Eclipse to open `Mydsl` files in the proper editor. But Xtext does not index these files and reports linking errors when I try to refer an element defined in `Mydsl` from any other file.

Is there a way to enable Xtext to process source files with fixed name but with no extension as well as regular files?

### UPD. 1

Accordingly to [Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053960/how-do-i-include-files-with-no-extension-for-my-xtext-dsl/8086732#8086732) I tried to specify a custom content type in `plugin.xml` of the main project:

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
    <content-type
         base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.text"
         file-extensions="mydsl"
         file-names="Mydsl"
         id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.contentType"
         name="My Language"
         priority="normal">
    </content-type>
</extension>
```

And binding it as follows:

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.xtext.content_resourceServiceProvider">
    <resourceServiceProvider
         class="org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslResourceServiceProvider"
         contentTypeIdentifier="org.xtext.example.mydsl.contentType">
    </resourceServiceProvider>
</extension>
```

But I still get linking errors as described above. I also added breakpoints into all methods of `MyDslResourceServiceProvider` and it seems that it doesn't even get instantiated or somehow invoked.

I also tried to move these extensions to the UI project but with no effect too.

### UPD. 2

Finally, I've done it.
Steps to get things work in a nutshell:

- Define new content type using `org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes` extension point
- Create a content handler by extending `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.PlatformContentHandlerImpl` class and override `canHandle(URI)` method to return `true` if and only if the argument is not `null`
- Register it with `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.content_handler`
- Create a new resource service provider with `canHandle(URI)` returning `true` always. One can extend `org.eclipse.xtext.resource.impl.DefaultResourceServiceProvider` and override the  corresponding method
- In the UI project bind it to `org.eclipse.xtext.content_resourceServiceProvider`, do not forget to specify an extension factory before the class name
- In the UI project register `org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceFactory` as `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.content_parser`, again with the extension factory
- Add content type bindings to `org.eclipse.ui.editors`, `org.eclipse.compare.contentViewers` and `org.eclipse.compare.contentMergeViewers`
- Depending on whether you need an old extension binding or not, remove `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.extension_parser` and `org.eclipse.xtext.extension_resourceServiceProvider` extensions

A change set (applied to a fresh project) for my case can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/embox/source/detail?r=4103).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to exploit the extension point for resource service providers and resource factories. It allows to register services / factory either by file extension or by content type. I think the latter should work if you provide a suitable content type for your files.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian! I will try it soon and tell about results.